# Can I use 2 different functions on the same route? Node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I have 2 different methods that I want to be called when a specific form is filled. I know that I can't have a form with 2 actions so I am just wondering can I call 2 different methods on the same route in Node.js?

I need something like this

```
router.post('/webmark/addcollection', webmarks.addCollection);
router.post('/webmark/addcollection', webmarks.uploadPicture);
```

so basically when the button in the form is pressed, the action would redirect to the specific route and the 2 methods would be called.

Comment: Can't you just put the `uploadPicture` inside the `addCollection?`

Comment: Think calling `next()` function in first route solve your problem

Comment: @Colin Thanks man, I looked over the code and that actually fixed my problem. Since no answers worked.

Comment: Cool, I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just put the `uploadPicture` inside the `addCollection` and it will work as you want.

Answer (score 3):

No, if do it that way, then you will be overwriting the first.

A better approach to that is like below:

```
router.post('/webmark/addcollection', webmarks.addCollection, webmarks.uploadPicture);
```

And make sure you make the call to next middleware function here `uploadPicture` from `addCollection` handler by adding `next()` in `addCollection` middleware on the successful operation.

```
exports.addCollection = function(req, res, next){
  // You logic goes here
  // On success operation call next middleware

  next();
}

exports.uploadPicture = function(req, res){
  // You logic for uploadPicture
}
```

Comment: This didn't work. It only called the addCollection method for some reason.

Comment: did you call next middleware in after successful operation in addCollection?

Answer (score 0):

Your first function receives 3 input `(request, response, next)`, at the end of this function, call `next()`.